# JQuery DataTables & Web API 2 OData column nested array data source

Tags: jquery, odata, datatables, asp.net-web-api2

When data is returned from a Web API 2.2 OData v4 controller with an OData metadata wrapper, I'm having trouble properly sourcing columns in the enumerated data set in JQuery DataTables. No error, simply "No data available in table" after initialization.

AJAX response:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost/blahblahblah/$metadata#SearchData","value":[
    {"ShipmentKey":"12345"},
    {"ShipmentKey":"12346"},
    {"ShipmentKey":"12347"},
    {"ShipmentKey":"12348"},
  ],"odata.nextLink":"http://localhost/blahblahblah/SearchData?$skip=100"
}
```

Datatables column intialiation:

```
"columns": [
                { "data": "value.ShipmentKey" },
            ]
```

Also tried:

```
"columns": [
                    { "data": "value..ShipmentKey" },
                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see, I needed to use dataSrc to specify "value" in my ajax setup.

```
$('#blah').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": 'http://localhost/blahblahblah/SearchData',
        "dataSrc": 'value'
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "ShipmentNumber" },
```